# AmCharts inline code Uncaught reference error

Tags: javascript, uncaught-exception, amcharts

Inside my HTML < body > I write Amcharts inline script like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var am_chartData = ...

    AmCharts.ready(function () {
        chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
        chart.dataProvider = am_chartData;
        ...
        ...
        chart.write('amcharts');
    });
</script>
```

At the end of the page I include js file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/amcharts.js"></script>
```

But in browser console I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: AmCharts is not defined
```

This error points the line of `AmCharts.ready(function () {`. It seems like browser can't find AmCharts when it reachs amcharts.ready line. When I include amcharts.js file in the < head > tag of page, everything works well. But I want to include it in the bottom of page.

Must I move all inline script to the end of the HTML file or is there a better solution that doesn't change my inline script position ?

Comment: are you able to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Just two thoughts.
Try to include the library before the call.
Also do check that the path is correct and loaded.